# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[] error in Java code

Tags: java

I'm receiving an error on the following Java code:

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {
  int larger = Math.min(nums[0],nums[2]);
  return larger;
}
```

> ```
> Error:    int larger [] = Math.min(nums[0],nums[2]);
>       ^^^^^^
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]
> ```

Why am I not able to calculate the minimum of 2 array values?

Comment: What do you think `cannot convert from int to int[]` means?

Comment: You are returning `larger` which is an `int` when your method declaration promises that you will return an `int[]`. Change it to `public int maxEnd3(int[] nums)`.

Comment: Er, your code doesn't agree with your error message - is it `int larger`, or `int larger[]`?

Comment: Beginner to coding...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return the larger in an array then change the return of the 
method `maxEnd3` to int and not array of int..

```
public int maxEnd3(int[] nums) {
  int larger = Math.min(nums[0],nums[2]);
  return larger;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is int[], so it is expecting int[] but you are returning a "large" which is an int. Try changing your return type to int or make "large"  int[].